# Symfony querybuilder set parameter with < (less than) value

Tags: symfony, query-builder

I need to get multiple values in my querybuilder.
In my `where` I have my value, and in `setparameter()` I try to get all values < 7, is it possible to do it with something like this?

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
->select('COUNT(d)')
->where('d.type = :type')
->setParameter('type', <=7)
->getQuery()->getfunctiont();
```

Comment: `->where('d.type <= :type')->setParameter('type', 7)`

Comment: you need to query for the `<` character or are you looking for value less than 7?

Comment: nice that was that, thank you ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use either [DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) or the [QueryBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html). E.g. in your EntityRepository you could do something like this:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
->select('COUNT(d)')
->where('d.type <= :type')
->setParameter('type', 7)
->getQuery()->getResult();
```

For even more complex scenarios take a look at the [Expr()](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class) class.

**NOTE: Avoid using DQL where not strictly necessary. It locks you into the ORM specific API, and is not really re-usable. There are some cases where DQL is required, but this is not one of those**